# Как можно получить скрытый API сайта

Tags: javascript, python, парсер, api, rest

**Суть:** парсер циан.

Нашёл [API циан](https://api.cian.ru/search-offers/v2/search-offers-desktop/), но там передаются не все данные. Решил не трогать API и парсить саму страничку, но прокси быстро улетают в бан, хотя задержка большая стоит. После этого решил покопаться в консоли разработчика и увидел в Response следующую картину:

[image: Response html странички]

Как я понял скрипт //cdn.cian.site/frontend/header-frontend/main.289cc52627b5bd8057f8.js генерирует страничку и делает XMLHttpRequest запросы внутри. Как мне определить и взять API из этого файла? Изменять я его не могу т.к. он сервере. Буду очень благодарен за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Никак. Это все живёт в рамках сессии. Сгенерился токен, с ним вот такой js запросы вне этого js работать не будут.

Я Апи маркета юзал через проки. При бане прокси она автоматом улетала в валгаллу. Но надо постоянно подкидывать прокси в топку